# Multiview load all tabs

Tags: c#, asp.net, multiview

I have multiview with 2 tabs

Each tab contains a usercontrol, problem is that when i am activate one of the tabs, multiview load both tabs ,which give performance problems. are there any wya to prevent that?

```
<asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0"  >
    <asp:View ID="Tab1" runat="server"  >

        <asp:Test1 runat="server" id="Test1" ></asp:Test1>
 </asp:View>
<asp:View ID="Tab2" runat="server">
   <asp:Test2 runat="server" id="Test2" ></asp:Test2>
</asp:View>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://msmvps.com/blogs/luisabreu/archive/2008/02/20/multiview-control-should-you-use-it.aspx

[How to avoid an asp:Multiview to load all the views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457898/how-to-avoid-an-aspmultiview-to-load-all-the-views)